# "Debug assertion failed" What's wrong with this sort? It should sort by year a dynamic list with movie objects

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-c++

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: c: program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm
Line: 2783

Expression: invalid iterator range
```

What's wrong with this sort? It should sort by year a dynamic list with movie objects.

```
bool cmp(Movie &m1, Movie &m2) {
return m1.getYear() - m2.getYear() < 0;
}
void Controller::sortByYear() {
std::sort(this->repo.getMovies().getAllElems(), this->repo.getMovies().getAllElems() + this->repo.getMovies().getSize(), cmp);
}
```

Comment: presumably you're iterating off the end of your container, any reason not to past `begin()` and `end()` or `back()`? Or is the issue that `Movie` doesn't implement the required interface to return an iterator for `sort`? It would help us to help you if you post a complete example that is runnable to take the guess work out

Comment: One guess is that one or more of the getters return by value, so the iterators end up referring to different temporary containers.

Comment: It doesn't work if I put begin() and end()... Here is my project and maybe you can take a look...   https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbvo947dxu5kz4i/LocalMovieDatabase.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line from Repository.h is your problem:

```
DynamicVector getMovies() const { return movies; }
```

You're returning a DynamicVector by value, instead of by reference, which means you're making a *copy* of the vector.

As a result, when the compiler hits

```
std::sort(
    this->repo.getMovies().getAllElems(),
    this->repo.getMovies().getAllElems() + this->repo.getMovies().getSize(),
    cmp);
```

It gets compiled as, "Make a copy of movies and pass a pointer to the beginning of that copy. Make a second copy of movies and pass a pointer to the end of that copy. Then sort from the beginning of one copy to the end of the other copy." This results in an assertion.

Typical C++ style would instead do something like

```
DynamicVector& getMovies() { return movies; }
const DynamicVector& getMovies() const { return movies; }
```

I.e., provide both `const` and non-`const` access to the vector.